# PhpStorm navigate to file by string value

Tags: phpstorm

I have a variable with file path like:

```
$file = '/some/file.txt';
```

or

```
var file = '/some/file.txt'
```

To edit `file.txt` I:

1. Left click on string.
2. Do `Extend Selection` shortcut.
3. Do `Navigate File...` shortcut.

Can I do it faster? For example, by clicking on `'/some/file.txt'` with some modifier key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and use **Navigate From Literal plugin** -- it works with any strings as it matches files by names.

It's not 100% perfect though .. as it seems to work rather with file names and even though the path in string is pretty unique .. it most likely will show a choice for all files named the same (e.g. `file.txt` in your case) -- at least this is what I remember when using it.